# Finding dependencies by grep in Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on a rather large project in pure C, and for various reasons we are not using CMake.

We have a good system which uses various shell commands to require very little maintanence. It will automatically find new headers and C files and add the headers to the dependencies and will compile the C files and include them in the output. However, we've gotten to the point where any changes we make to the header files becomes a problem because it requires a recompilation of the entire project, rather than just the C files that include it directly or indirectly.

I've worked on a system to ensure that the only header files which are added as dependencies are ones which are required by the C file itself (recursively up the tree).

I had thought I would be able to solve this myself, but it seems that make has rather inconsistent rules for expansion of variables.

The solution I came up with was to try to use ag and get all the includes out of the file. This works as intended, and I pipe it into tr so that I can ensure that no newlines are added, thereby messing up make. The issue that I'm having though is in determining which file to search in. This is the recipe that it's using for the section in question:

```
$(GAMEOBJDIR)/%.o : $(GAMEDIR)/%.c $(shell ag -o '(?<=(^#include "))(.*?)(?=("$$))' $(GAMEDIR)/%.c | tr '\n' ' ')
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(if $(RELEASE),$(RELFLAGS),$(DBFLAGS)) -c -o $@ $<
```

The problem is that `$(GAMEDIR)/%.c` is expanding to `src/game/%.c` and not `src/game/<filename>.c`. I'm unsure how to fix this issue based on the expansion rules of make.

Once I can figure this out I'll be able to make sure this walks up the chain of header files too, but until I can get this figured out I have no reason to work on that.

Answer (score 1):

Make's rules for expansion are completely consistent... but sometimes they aren't what people want.  That's not the same thing :)

Rules for expansion are explained [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles).  In your case you're working with a prerequisite list which means the variables are expanded as the makefile is parsed.  That includes the shell command and all other variables.  Because you are working with a pattern rule, it means that at the time the makefile is parsed it doesn't match any particular file, it's just defining the pattern rule itself.  So, `%` can't be expanded here.  It will be expanded later, when make starts walking the dependency graph and trying to locate ways to build targets.

In general your method cannot work efficiently.  You *could* defer the expansion of these parts of the prerequisites list using [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html#Secondary-Expansion).  However, that means every time make wants to TRY to use this pattern it will run these commands--that will just be slow.

Have you considered using a more standard way to manage detecting prerequisites?  Try reading [this description](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) for example to see if it would work for you.